# Split text with Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets with 1,500 cells containing items like:

```
1,300 users  
2236 users, 12 companies  
15000 users,153 companies  
<46,000 users, <200 companies
```

I need to split this content into two columns that would look like:

```
1300  
2236      12
15000     153
46000     200
```

Commas don't succeed as the delimiter in a simple `SPLIT()` function, nor does spacing.

Any ideas what I can do here?

Comment: @pnuts I cannot make any assumptions about where and how the commas have been used. This data was collected by a freelancer and she simply copied/pasted data from many different sources.

Comment: @pnuts Yes, I would like the operation to be accurate and split `users,153`. I would be OK with doing a recursive operation if that's what's necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a quite pragmatic approach to reach your goal.

### Formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   SPLIT(                        // string
     REGEXREPLACE(
       A1:A4,                    // text
       "[users,<=>compani]",     // regular_expression
       ""                        // replacement
     ),                          
   " ")                          // delimiter
 )

copy/paste
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A4, "[users,<=>compani]",""), " "))
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Explained

The *regular_expression* is cleaning up the string, in preparation for the `SPLIT`. The *replacement*  is simply set to contain an empty string. The result, yields a string that contains one or two values, separated by a white space. The *delimiter* in the `SPLIT` is set accordingly and all is put into an `ARRAYFORMULA`.

Comment: Was this with the old version of Sheets? I copied this exact data and formula and can't get it to output the array, the only output is 1300.

Comment: The old, just found the original sheet I prepared.

Answer (score 1):

Rather a rigmarole but if I explain correctly should work, I suggest testing on a copy:

1. select data (assumed to be ColumnA), Edit, Find and Replace..., Find `[a-z].`, select Search using regular expressions, Replace all.
2. change Find to `<` , Replace all.
3. in B1 put `=split(a1," ")` and copy down to suit.
4. copy B:C to E1 and Edit, Paste Special...., Paste Values only.
5. select ColumnF, Edit, Find and Replace..., Find `s`, Replace all.
6. move or copy ColumnsE:F where required and delete sheet.