# Split a column of strings with a single formula returning an array

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column of strings like this:

```
+---------+
| a bb    |
| ccc d   |
| ee ffff |
+---------+
```

(exactly one space in each string), which I'd like to split by the space into two columns:

```
+-----+------+
| a   | bb   |
| ccc | d    |
| ee  | ffff |
+-----+------+
```

This can be done by putting `B1 =split(A1," ")` and dragging down the column. But I'm looking for an `arrayformula` version of this.

Unsuccessful attempt: the formula  `=arrayformula(split(A1:A3," "))` throws #VALUE error: "Function SPLIT parameter 1 value should be non-empty."

Comment: I don't get and error for `=arrayformula(split(A1:A3," "))` but it doesn't work  for me as desired anyway.

Comment: @Rubén Are you using Old Sheets for this? Mine is New. In [this answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/57174) Jacob used arrayformula-split, and it was in an old sheet.

Comment: I'm using the new Google Sheets too.

Comment: For an alternative formula using regex and being able to handle multiple columns, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/30202802/1595451

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google introduced a built-in tool for this purpose: [Split text to columns](http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.com/2016/03/easily-convert-text-to-columns-in.html).

1. Select a range to split, keeping in mind the separator menu will be at the bottom of this range (this is not very convenient for splitting a very tall column).
2. Use "Split column to text" from the menu
3. Select a separator.
4. **Warning**: the cells to the right of the column you are splitting may be overwritten when the column splits.

[image: separator]

Answer (score 3):

A variation of Normal's formula using only one regexextract (assuming data in col A, starting in row 2)

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(A2:A), regexextract(A2:A, {"^[^ ]+","[^ ]+$"}),))
```

Comment: For the record: to split by another character, such as a comma, one would replace `[^ ]` with `[^,]` in two places.

Comment: There is a side effect of using one regexextract to get both pieces: when splitting strings like "abc 123", the second result ends up being text rather than a number. The long version `{regexextract(A2:A, "^[^ ]+"),  regexextract(A2:A,"[^ ]+$")}` makes 123 a number.

Comment: @404 justed tested. It doesn't (not for me at least). :-/ Shouldn't come as a surprise though: regex operates on text. If you wanted to convert the second part to a number you'd need something like: =arrayformula({regexextract(A2:A3;"^[^ ]+")\ regexextract(A2:A3;"[^ ]+$")+0})

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer

```
=ArrayFormula(
   {
      Left(A1:A3,FIND(" ",A1:A3)-SIGN(ROW(A1:A3))),
      Right(A1:A3,Len(A1:A3)-Find(" ",A1:A3))
    }
 )
```

## Explanation

Looks that `SPLIT()` doesn't "like" having arrays as input parameters but `LEFT()`,`RIGHT()`,`FIND()` and `LEN()` work well with them.

An array with two columns is used.
The first column is obtained with `LEFT()`.
The second column is obtained with `RIGHT()`.
`FIND()` is used to find the position of the column separator.
As we don't want the separator as part of the first column, we require an array to subtract 1 to each row (`SIGN(ROW(A1:A3))`).
`LEN()-FIND()` give us the number of characters to be taken by `RIGHT()`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a regex-based formula similar to [Rubén's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/88531/revisions):

```
=arrayformula({regexextract(A1:A3,"^[^ ]+"), regexextract(A1:A3,"[^ ]+$")})
```

Here, `^[^ ]+` means: all non-space characters at the beginning of string, and `[^ ]+$` means: all non-space characters at the end of string. One can replace space by comma, etc: for example, `[^,]`

This is only meant for strings containing exactly one separator: otherwise, the output will be wrong.

#### Custom function

To handle splitting into an arbitrary number of strings, I wrote a custom function which can be used as `arraysplit(A1:A3, " ")`. It accepts column ranges (or single cells) as the first parameter, and separator as the second parameter.

Unlike the built-in `split` function, this one does not ignore empty strings: e.g., `a,b,,c` split by comma becomes four cells, the third of them blank. (In my opinion, ignoring empty strings is a major flaw in the design of the built-in `split` function.)

```
/**
 * Splits a column of strings by a separator.
 *
 * @param {A1:A3} range    Column range or a single cell
 * @param {" "} separator  Separating character or substring
 * @returns                Substrings, including empty strings
 * @customfunction
 */
function arraysplit(range, separator) {
  if (range.constructor !== Array) {
    range = [[range]];    // handle single-cell input
  }
  if (range[0].length !== 1) {
    throw new Error('First argument must be a column range');
  }
  var i, j, split, output = [], width = 1;
  for (i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
    split = range[i][0].split(separator);
    output.push(split);  
    width = Math.max(width, split.length);   // max number of pieces 
  }
  for (i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < width - output[i].length; j++) {
      output[i].push('');   // empty string to make rectangular array
    }
  }
  return output;
}
```

Bonus feature: unlike the built-in split, `arraysplit` accepts empty string as a separator, in which case it splits the strings into separate characters. (Of course, this behavior is simply inherited from the JavaScript's split method.)

Comment: Your function could return the error message as a custom error message instead of returning a result by using `throw`. See https://mogsdad.wordpress.com/2015/07/08/did-you-know-custom-functions-in-google-apps-script/

Comment: That's good to know; included.

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
=arrayformula({split(A1:A3," ")})
```

It works for me.

Comment: There is no need to use curly braces on this formula.