# How to do you extract characters from a string in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a string in a cell: `A|BCD|EF|GHI|JK`.

I would like to extract it separate in individual cells: `A` should be in one cell, `BCD` in the next, `EF` in the next, and so on.

I would appreciate any help on this. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of you search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Possible duplicate [Split a column of strings with a single formula returning an array](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/88517/88163)

Comment: Once? Just for one cell? Your question misses information, please [edit] it in.

Answer (score 1):

You can split text using menu Google Sheets option *Data - Split text to columns*:
[image]

On next step select *Separator: Custom*

[image]

Result:

[image]